# SSIS Conditional Filter split with bit data type

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis, ssis-data-types

Data -  from table (58 columns), in this table 4 columns will use in conditional filter.

1 column - bit data type(Color_Ind)

1 column -  bit data type(Type_ind)

2 columns - varchar data type(Region,State)

process steps
1) OLE DB connection to extract all data

2) use Data Conversion to convert bit type columns into string data type.

3) use conditional filter to filter the data into 5 different category.

Probelm:-
- If I use color_ind and Type_ind it will not create my desired output, but If I use it without these columns and only use Region and state it will create my desired output.

Could you please tell me how to use bit data type into condtional filter in SSIS?

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question. You need to explain in more detail why the bit columns don't create your output and exactly what the problem is that you want to solve. And if you can filter successfully on only `Region` and `State` then why are the bit columns needed?

Comment: Not sure what this ("If I use color_ind and Type_ind it will not create my desired out put.") means...what is your desired output?

Comment: Hi,I got my ans.it at here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/a0c4dbe0-bbe1-421f-b2fe-b72dce4d224e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answare from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/a0c4dbe0-bbe1-421f-b2fe-b72dce4d224e post...

Thanks for your efforts.